# PayPal JS SDK - Credit card Pay/submit button has no text for some countries

Tags: paypal

I'm currently trying to integrate PayPal payments on a website, but I have an issue, the button to submit the credit card form is empty.

Here is my integration

HTML :

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=MY_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID&currency=EUR&locale=fr_FR"></script>
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
```

JS :

```
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: "10"
          }
        }],
        application_context: {
          shipping_preference: 'NO_SHIPPING'
        }
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        console.log(details);
      });
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Even with this basic code from the PayPal doc, the credit card submit button is empty as below :
[image]

When inspecting the DOM, the button innerText is empty. Here is a fiddle showing the issue : https://jsfiddle.net/dkLg49n2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be present only in some languages including French, but if you change the language there the button fills up with text again ...

I am also trying to find a workaround and difficult to report a bug to paypal...
I did not find the location dedicated to this.

So badly done.

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/mts would be the place, however PayPal is already aware of the issue

Comment: Thanks dbl-bzh for finding it out ! Preston PHX, we could not know that Paypal is aware, as they do not have any incident tracker

Comment: Right, I was letting him know both how to report such an issue (since he didn't know how), and that there's no need at this point.  I've also been told that this will be fixed in the next release (whenever that happens, likely some days)

Answer (score -1):

This is a PayPal bug affecting all European countries at the moment; seems to be missing translation text for that button.

Anyone can reproduce the issue directly at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , clicking the black button and selecting the flag of a European country.

Update: I've been told this will be fixed in PayPal's next release of the component, whenever that happens